# Form not start a workflow

Tags: workflow, custom-form

I using SharePoint 2013.
I have several forms of editing for the same item. I also have a workflow that starts when editing an item.
I would like a form not initiate this workflow.

is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried setting the "Allow this workflow to be manually started" start option and unchecked the other options?  Are you only trying to disable this feature one-time while you edit?  Your question is a little hazy...

Comment: Actually, I have more than 3 forms for the same item. In this form I do not want to start any workflow. If I find no other alternative, I'll use a control column not to start the flow. I like to use a native SharePoint solution...